# validate two excel files and create another excel file for the mismatching records by using GUI in Python Tkinter

Tags: python, excel

I have a code to compare two excel/csv files and generate another excel/csv file in this file contains mismatching data. This code is execute successfully and create new excel file.
Can some one help me how to do same things in GUI in python. I have a sample diagram for this.

My Code :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dftableauserver = pd.read_excel('D:\Backup\Excel File Data Validation\Tableau Server\Tableau Server.xlsx')

dftableauonline = pd.read_excel('D:\Backup\Excel File Data Validation\Tableau Online\Tableau Online.xlsx')

#print(dftableauserver.equals(dftableauonline))

comparevalues = dftableauserver.values == dftableauonline.values
#print(comparevalues)


rows,cols = np.where(comparevalues==False)

for item in zip(rows,cols):
    dftableauserver.iloc[item[0],item[1]] = '{} Not Equal {}'.format(dftableauserver.iloc[item[0],item[1]],dftableauonline.iloc[item[0],item[1]])


dftableauserver.to_excel('D:\Backup\Excel File Data Validation\Validation\Validation_Output.xlsx', index=False,header=True)

print("Validation File Generated Sucessfully")
```

Thanks,
Allabkshu.

Comment: first select code in question and use `Ctrl+K` to format it.

Comment: what GUI do you mean? `tkinter`, `PyQt`, `wxPython`, `PyGTK`, `kivy`, etc. , or maybe web page (`Flask`, `Django`, `Bottle`, etc.)